# How to delete tableview row in split view controller

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsmutablearray, nsindexpath

I am trying to delete a tableview row that is displayed in my split view controller. When i swipe left and click delete, my App crashes, and i get the error:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (44) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (44), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

I did manage to get the re-arrange option working for the table view without any errors. For the delete row function, I did the following:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:  (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [_objects removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
    withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];   
}
```

But there must be something i am missing. Maybe a simple update tableview. I think i tried it but to no luck.

I know its going to be hard to determine how with just one method in my project. You can view my entire project here:

https://github.com/mithunan/presidents-splitView

Any help is gratefully appreciated.

EDIT----

This is the numberOfRowsInSection Method:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.presidents count];
}
```

and this method might also help...

```
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
    id object = [self.presidents objectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row];
    [_objects removeObjectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row];
    [_objects insertObject:object atIndex:toIndexPath.row];
}
```

Thank you

EDIT 2 -------------

Based on info provided by rmaddy, I changed the commitEditingStyle...

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self.presidents removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

}
```

But now im getting a build error: no visible @interface for NSArray declares the selector 'removeObjectAtIndex:'

Sorry if i am asking for to much, but could you please walk me through this.

Comment: What version of iOS are you testing on?

Comment: I tested on my 7.0 on actual device, and 7.1 on simulator on xcode 5.  Note: I created the app in xcode6 beta 2. But had target to ios 7.0.

Comment: There is are bugs in iOS 8 but under iOS 7 it should work. Two things: 1) Check that `_objects` is not `nil` when `commitEditingStyle` is called. 2) Confirm that your `numberOfRowsInSection` is returning the proper new number of rows after removing an object from `_objects`.

Comment: i added a breakpoint inside the commitEditingStyle method, on the deleteRowsAtIndexPaths line, and in the bottom debug window, it says _objects is nil. Im relatively new to this, and am unsure what i should do next.

Comment: That's the problem then. Since `_objects` is `nil` you don't update your data model to reflect the deleted row. Post your `numberOfRowsInSection` method in your question. What does it use to return the number of rows? Is it `_objects` or something else?

Comment: i used return [self.presidents count];... i edited original post, see above. Do i have to do something like above?

Comment: There you go. Your data source is based on `self.presidents` but for some unknown reason, you attempt to update `_objects`. That makes no sense. You need to use the same data. Remove the object from `self.presidents` instead of `_objects`. Same with the move.

Comment: @rmaddy I dont think i understand this as i should. I tried what you said but got another error, build error. Please see Edit 2 in my original question. Also, I attached the project to GIT hub... https://github.com/mithunan/presidents-splitView   Could you please give me a bit more detailed info on how i could fix this issue. The rows are rearranging. P.S., my data is coming in from a plist. Thank you so much.

Comment: You need to make your `presidentsArray` mutable.

Answer (score 1):

It's always a good idea to add `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` method calls whenever you change your table view model:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:  (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView beginUpdates];
    [_objects removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                     withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    [tableView endUpdates];
}
```

From the documentation of `beginUpdates` method:

> Begin a series of method calls that insert, delete, or select rows and
>   sections of the receiver. Call this method if you want subsequent
>   insertions, deletion, and selection operations (for example,
>   cellForRowAtIndexPath: and indexPathsForVisibleRows) to be animated
>   simultaneously. This group of methods must conclude with an invocation
>   of endUpdates. These method pairs can be nested. If you do not make
>   the insertion, deletion, and selection calls inside this block, table
>   attributes such as row count might become invalid. You should not call
>   reloadData within the group; if you call this method within the group,
>   you will need to perform any animations yourself.

Comment: The use of `begin/endUpdates` should not be necessary when only making one call to delete, insert, or reload rows.

Comment: @rmaddy I am not saying it's necessary in all cases, but from my experience it may fix some strange behaviour when multiple calls to update table view happen simultaneously.

Comment: But that's not the case here. It's a simple swipe-to-delete with one call to `deleteRows`. And it appears that the data source is being properly updated as needed. The use of `begin/endUpdates` is not needed. Now having said all of that, it does seem that iOS 8 has a bunch of table view bugs. I've run into several. Your answer actually does work around an iOS 8 bug but it shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: i tried adding your suggestion but i still get the same error.

Comment: @rmaddy Yes, I had to deal with `UITableView` bugs on iOS 8 too and this workaround helped me. It doesn't hurt to call these methods if it fixes the problem, right?

Comment: @RinatKhanov what you should do is create a simple test app that demonstrates the bug and submit a bug report to Apple. That way they can fix the problem so everyone doesn't have to add hacks to their code. It doesn't "hurt" to add the `begin/endUpdate` calls to fix it in one place. It does hurt when you have to go back and modify dozens of classes that have worked since iOS 3.0 due to a bug in iOS 8. :)